# convert unicode escape sequences to string

Tags: c#, unicode, escaping, sequences

Hi I have this problem. From server I get JSON string as unicode escape sequences an I need convert this sequences to unicode string. I find some solution, but any doesn’t work for all json response.

For example from server I get this string.

```
string encodedText="{\"DATA\":{\"idUser\":18167521,\"nick\":\"KecMessanger2\",\"photo\":\"1\",\"sex\":1,\"photoAlbums\":0,\"videoAlbums\":0,\"sefNick\":\"kecmessanger2\",\"profilPercent\":0,\"emphasis\":false,\"age\":25,\"isBlocked\":false,\"PHOTO\":{\"normal\":\"http://213.215.107.125/fotky/1816/75/n_18167521.jpg?v=1\",\"medium\":\"http://213.215.107.125/fotky/1816/75/m_18167521.jpg?v=1\",\"24x24\":\"http://213.215.107.125/fotky/1816/75/s_18167521.jpg?v=1\"},\"PLUS\":{\"active\":false,\"activeTo\":\"0000-00-00\"},\"LOCATION\":{\"idRegion\":\"1\",\"regionName\":\"Banskobystricku00fd kraj\",\"idCity\":\"109\",\"cityName\":\"Rimavsku00e1 Sobota\"},\"STATUS\":{\"isLoged\":true,\"isChating\":false,\"idChat\":0,\"roomName\":\"\",\"lastLogin\":1291898043},\"PROJECT_STATUS\":{\"photoAlbums\":0,\"photoAlbumsFavs\":0,\"videoAlbums\":0,\"videoAlbumsFavs\":0,\"videoAlbumsExts\":0,\"blogPosts\":0,\"emailNew\":0,\"postaNew\":0,\"clubInvitations\":0,\"dashboardItems\":26},\"STATUS_MESSAGE\":{\"statusMessage\":\"Nepru00edtomnu00fd.\",\"addTime\":\"1291887539\"},\"isFriend\":false,\"isIamFriend\":false}}";
```

statusMessage in jsonstring consist **Nepru00edtomnu00fd**, in .net unicode string is it **Neprítomný**.

region in jsonstring consist **Banskobystricku00fd** in .net unicode string is it **BanskoBystrický**.

**Other examples:**

1. Nepru00edtomnu00fd  -> Neprítomný
2. Banskobystricku00fd -> BanskoBystrický
3. Trenu010du00edn     -> Trenčín

I need convert unicode escape sequences  to .net string in slovak language.

On converting I used this func:

```
private static string UnicodeStringToNET(string input)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"\\[uU]([0-9A-F]{4})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return input = regex.Replace(input, match => ((char)int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value,
      NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
}
```

Where can be problem?

Comment: I'd highly recommend replacing your actual IP address in the JSON string with a bogus one for purpose getting help.

Comment: This is borked, fix the server.

Comment: Yeah, if you replace every sequence of `u` followed by four hex digits you're going to be messing up valid words. If backslashes have gone missing the original content is unrecoverable. You need to find out where those backslashes are getting removed, and stop that happening. (Misguided anti-SQL-injection scanner gone crazy?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your escape sequences do not start with a \ like "\u00fd" so you Regex should be only

```
"[uU]([0-9A-F]{4})"
```

...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method (based on previous answers) that I wrote to do the job. It handles both \uhhhh and \Uhhhhhhhh, and it will preserve escaped unicode escapes (so if your string needs to contain a literal \uffff, you can do that). The temporary placeholder character \uf00b is in a [private use area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Area), so it shouldn't typically occur in Unicode strings.

```
    public static string ParseUnicodeEscapes(string escapedString)
    {
        const string literalBackslashPlaceholder = "\uf00b";
        const string unicodeEscapeRegexString = @"(?:\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4}))|(?:\\U([0-9a-fA-F]{8}))";
        // Replace escaped backslashes with something else so we don't
        // accidentally expand escaped unicode escapes.
        string workingString = escapedString.Replace("\\\\", literalBackslashPlaceholder);

        // Replace unicode escapes with actual unicode characters.
        workingString = new Regex(unicodeEscapeRegexString).Replace(workingString,
            match => ((char) Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber))
            .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        // Replace the escaped backslash placeholders with non-escaped literal backslashes.
        workingString = workingString.Replace(literalBackslashPlaceholder, "\\");
        return workingString;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct for characters above 0xFFFF. Casting an Int32 to a char would truncate the value.